# JAXB Wrapper+Adapter Ignoring Output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

So I have abit of an odd issue. I have an XML element wrapped, and that element needs to be parsed then converted to a different type.

I figured if I use @XmlElement(type=PlaceHolder.class) I can have JAXB parse all the needed information into the PlaceHolder and then use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to convert the PlaceHolder into the class I need.

This is the output from System.out

```
||tree.log, 1  tree.log
tree.log x 1/2
||test.oo, 2  null
||craft.lumber, 2  null
wb.lumber Lumber 10.0 | 0 -> 0
```

which makes me believe

1. The xml is parsed into the PlaceHolder class(XMLItemStack)
2. The Adapter does attempt to convert the PlaceHolder class
3. The output from the Adapter is ignored.

XML

```
<recipe id="wb.lumber">
    <name>Lumber</name>
    <time>10</time>
    <building>workbench</building>
    <in>
        <item id="tree.log">
            <stack>1</stack>
        </item>
        <item id="test.oo">
            <stack>2</stack>
        </item>
    </in>
    <out>
        <item id="craft.lumber">
            <stack>2</stack>
        </item>
    </out>
</recipe>
```

MainClass

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Recipe {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    String id;
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    @XmlElement
    float time;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="in")
    @XmlElement(name="item",type=XMLItemStack.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(xmlToItemStackAdapter.class)
    ItemStack[] req;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="out")
    @XmlElement(name="item",type=XMLItemStack.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(xmlToItemStackAdapter.class)
    ItemStack[] res;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str = id+" "+name+" "+time+" | "+(req == null ? 0 : req.length)+" -> "+(res == null ? 0 : res.length);
        return str;
    }
}
```

Adapter and Placeholder Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
static class XMLItemStack {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    String id;
    @XmlElement
    int stack;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return id+" "+stack;
    }

    public XMLItemStack(){}

    public XMLItemStack(String name,int size){
        id = name;
        stack = size;
    }
}

static class xmlToItemStackAdapter extends XmlAdapter<XMLItemStack,ItemStack> {

    @Override
    public XMLItemStack marshal(ItemStack v) throws Exception {
        return new XMLItemStack(v.getItem().getID(),v.getCount());
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack unmarshal(XMLItemStack v) throws Exception {
        Item it = Items.getItem(v.id);
        System.out.println("||"+v.id+", "+v.stack+"  "+it);

        if(it == null){
            throw new Exception("Unable to Find Item for Crafting Recipe");
        }

        System.out.println(new ItemStack(it,v.stack));

        return new ItemStack(it,v.stack);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super confused.

With or without specifying the @XmlElement type, and changing ItemStack[] into an array list solved the problem.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Recipe {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    String id;
    @XmlElement
    String name;
    @XmlElement
    float time;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="in")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(xmlToItemStackAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="item",type=XMLItemStack.class)
    ArrayList<ItemStack> req;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="out")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(xmlToItemStackAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    ArrayList<ItemStack> res;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str = id+" "+name+" "+time+" | "+(req == null ? 0 : req.size())+" -> "+(res == null ? 0 : res.size());
        return str;
    }
}
```